# Disable screenshots and leave only the icons while Alt-TAB on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 19.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 19.04 and noticed that when alt tabbing, a preview of the app is shown instead of the icon. Can I set the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> switcher to display only icons instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The window switcher, which appears when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, can be set to display only the thumbnail of the window, only the app icon or both. The setting to change this is not exposed to the user, but can be changed using a command. Open a terminal and copy/paste following command to have the window switcher only show the application icon.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher app-icon-mode 'app-icon-only'
```

Change `app-icon-only` to `thumbnail-only` or `both` for the other options. Reset to default with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.window-switcher app-icon-mode
```

In Gnome Shell, the desktop environment used by Ubuntu, this and many other configuration settings can also be viewed and edited using a graphical tool, `dconf-editor`, which is not installed by default.